# Currying and Recursion

Tags: python, functional-programming

My question is closely related to the question here:
[Function chaining in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038358/function-chaining-in-python#)
, which is the **"A chain adding function"** problem on CodeWars.
There're many useful solutions in the link, but I just want to find out what's wrong with my own solution.

The first thing that comes up to my mind is using Currying, for example

```
def add(a):
    def add2(b):
        return b + a
    return add2

add(1)(2)
```

will give me `3` as output.

Now I want to add recursion so that `add(1)`, `add(1)(2)(3)` and `add(1)(2)(3)(4)` etc. can also work as expected:

```
def add(a):
    if not callable(a):
        return a
    else:
        def add2(b):
            return b + add(a)
        return add2
```

This time `add(1)` returns `1` as expected, but `add(1)(2)`, `add(1)(2)(3)` etc. gives me error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong here? Furthermore, how to resolve it? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function chaining in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038358/function-chaining-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

When you call it with `add(1)` then `a` is `1` (so not callable) and it will return `1`. Next step: You'll have `1(2)` but because `1` is not a callable this fails.

> Furthermore, how to resolve it?

You cannot, because you would need to know when to end the recursion, but you only know if you need to go a level deeper **after** you completed the current step completely. So unfortunately your chosen approach will not work and you have to look for a different approach. That's where your [link to the question about function chaining comes in.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038358/function-chaining-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

@MSeifert is right actually should be duplicate, but as you can do:

```
class myint(int):
    def __call__(self, i):
        return myint(self + i)
def add(v):
    return myint(v)
```

Now:

```
>>> add(1)(2)
3
>>> add(1)(2)(3)
6
```

Or a one-liner:

```
class add(int):__call__ = lambda self, v: add(self+v)
```

Or another one-liner:

```
add = lambda v: type("", (int,), {"__call__": lambda self, v: self.__class__(self + v)})(v)
```

Every one of them outputs:

```
>>> add(1)(2)
3
>>> add(1)(2)(3)
6
```

Comment: Is that copied (apart from different variable names) from the duplicate?

Comment: @MSeifert Yeah that's right but wanted the OP to understand, but actually yeah i think i should delete my answer

Comment: @MSeifert I do this because looks like OP saw this but can't embed it (i have no idea why?)

Comment: @U9-Forward Thank you for your answer, I have looked through all solutions to the linked question before asking my own. Those solutions didn't resolve my concern so I asked a new one.